# Automated way to convert XML files to SQL database?

Tags: mysql, xml, postgresql, schema

We have a bunch of XML files, following a schema which is essentially a serialised database form:

```
<table1>
   <column1>value</column1>
   <column2>value</column2>
</table1>
<table1>
   <column1>another value</column1>
   <column2>another value</column2>
</table1>
...
```

Is there a really easy way to turn that into an SQL database? Obviously I can manually construct the schema, identify all tables, fields etc, and then write a script to import it. I just wonder if there are any tools that could automate some or all of that process?

Comment: Which SQL is it?  Some, like Oracle, provide native support for importing XML into a table.

Comment: Oh. Either Postgres or MySQL - not fussed. (But nothing commercial.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Mysql please see the [`LOAD XML` Syntax<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html).

It should work without any additional XML transformation for the XML you've provided, just specify the format and define the table inside the database firsthand with matching column names:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'table1.xml'
    INTO TABLE table1
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<table1>';
```

There is also a related question:

- [How to import XMl file into MySQL database table using XML_LOAD(); function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5491056/367456)

For Postgresql I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [project on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61765/Using-XSLT-to-Generate-SQL-Script) that makes it simple to convert an XML file to SQL Script. It uses XSLT. You could probably modify it to generate the DDL too.

And See this question too : [Generating SQL using XML and XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319159/generating-sql-using-xml-and-xslt)

Comment: Great, that's a really helpful starting point. Googling for the DDL part turns up this: http://xml2ddl.berlios.de/

Comment: @steve that link is dead now, could you possibly point me to the current project, or anywhere you may have found a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I'm  steve but [I've found a fork of it on git hub](https://github.com/charlesnagy/xml2ddl)

Answer (score 1):

If there is XML file with 2 different tables then will:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'table1.xml' INTO TABLE table1 
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'table1.xml' INTO TABLE table2
```

work

Comment: All these methods require you to manually construct the table first.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://www.ehow.com/how_6613143_convert-xml-code-sql.html

for downloading the tool 
http://www.xml-converter.com/

Comment: Looks like that tool goes the opposite direction. The tutorial links to some other options.